# How to setup multiple login managers in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Is it possible to setup multiple login managers in Flask? I have 3 pages with different content that need to be password protected:

```
mydomain.com/page1
mydomain.com/page2
mydomain.com/page3
```

Anyone logged in and accessing page1 **should not** have access to page2 or page3 (and vice-versa).

I guess one way is to specify `username` in my jinja2 template and show page results based on that. For example, I could add:

```
{% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.username == 'abc' %}
<!-- show HTML for user 'abc' only -->
```

But using this method, page2 and page3 would still be accessible. They just wouldn't show any content because nothing would be defined for those users in the jinja2 template.

Here's how I currently have the `LoginManager()` setup:

```
lm = LoginManager()
lm.init_app(app)
lm.login_view = 'login'

class User():
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return self.username

    @staticmethod
    def validate_login(password_hash, password):
        return check_password_hash(password_hash, password)

@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    user = myUsers.find_one({"User": id})
    if not user:
        return None
    return User(user['User'])

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("dashboard"))
        return redirect(url_for("dashboard"))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
            user = myUsers.find_one({"User": form.username.data})
            if user and User.validate_login(user['Password'], form.password.data):
                user_obj = User(user['User'])
                login_user(user_obj)
                return redirect(request.args.get("next") or url_for("dashboard"))
            flash("Wrong username or password. Please try again.", category='error')
        return render_template('/login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

Comment: Add [Flask-Principle](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/) to work with Flask-Login. See [Granular Resource Protection](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Principal/#granular-resource-protection) in the docs.

Comment: @pjcunningham Thank you. I will take a look.

Answer (score 1):

This post doesn't answer your question directly, but I hope it can provide another perspective to your problem. My solution would be to implement a custom [view decorator](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/) and a `role` field in your User class to restrict user access.

Comment: Thank you. I already started experimenting with `role`. Basically it's another thing that gets called as part of the `User` class. Then in my jinja2 template, I show content based on roles, like `{% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.role == 'admin' %} <!-- add content here --> {% endif %}`. Would prefer to do this on server side though.

Comment: View decorator is server side. In the example, you can see that if user is not logged in, the view won't be rendered.